# Convergence of BMO norm

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I am studying Stein's Functional Analysis.
I worked for a long time but cannot check the following proposition:

Let $f$ be a real valued BMO function, define $f^k$, the truncation of $f$ by

$$f^k(x)= \begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if }|f|<k,\\k &\text{if }f\ge k, \\-k &\text{if }f\le -k\end{cases}$$

Then, $f^k$ is a sequence of BMO functions. The part I cannot solve is $\|f^k\|$ converges to $\|f\|$, where the norm is BMO norm.

Comment: How are you comparing a function $f$ and an integer $k$ with $\leq$ and $\geq$?

Comment: Of course its value at x